# How to reference Excel Column A ruby code

Tags: ruby, cells, import-from-excel

Im writing a ruby code to pull data from a table component.

I can reference the values of each cell by

```
model.budget['a1'] = salary

model.budget['c1'] = $900.00
```

where budget is just the name of the whole table component. This works fine. But I want to reference the column header "A" not the cells. I want to pull those values but how can I??

Comment: Is this an .XLS file? A .CSV? .XLSX?

Comment: Well its using an online system with a table component that is very similar to excel. Still learning excel so im not sure what the difference is between those but Im sure its important. But if you have an example for either that would be helpful...??  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other code written? It's just about impossible to extrapolate from what little you've shown. How is the data pulled in? See what I'm getting at here?

Comment: Unfortunately its work related so I cant give too much information. If you were using command prompt with ruby and rails to extract the data. How would your code be? just to get the the value for column header "A" instead of getting the value of a cell (Ex. A1). Lets say its .XLSX file or which ever one you know. How would you do this?

Comment: I showed how I would try this in my answer below. Did you try it? What have you tried? You might get lucky and someone might decide to write your program for you and post it here. But this is all volunteer, so people will be less likely to help when you don't put effort into your question. I'm pretty sure that "how to read the header from Excel with Ruby" is not a trade secret. You can post code with made up examples that have nothing to do with your employer.

Comment: And If I was importing from .XSLX I'd have to use a gem. What gem are you using? Ruby-XL? Spreadsheet? Simple-spreadsheet? Roo?

Comment: Yes Ive tried what you suggested before. No luck. But the code is literally that simple. (model.budget['a1'] ). There's no other code. Its a pretty cool system with a lot of functionalities. Sorry I couldn't provide more information. Thanks anyways.